What is meant by speed of a CPU or speed of a RAM module?
What is exactly meant by when one says the speed of RAM is 5MHz and CPU is 3GHz? Aren't they just semiconductor chips composed of logic gates,transistors and capacitors (logic gates are also made up of transistors)? Isn't the number of clock pulses (frequency) the only thing that limits the speed at which things get executed?
Shouldn't people say that the clock speed of a motherboard is in GHz? If not what, limits the speed of a chip and what is meant by it? Especially for RAM, since RAM doesn't have a clock on its own. What do we even mean by the speed of RAM? Shouldn't the speed only depend on the speed of the motherboard's clock for CPU and RAM?
I am really confused. Even after a long search I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

RAM does have a clock of it's own, why do you say it doesn't?

@Justme oh sory I wasn't aware of it.It clears some of my confusion.But what limits the rate at which a semiconductor operates?why Can't a semiconductor can't operate beyond some Hz? What happens if it pushed beyond it? I know my question is long and I have many doubts but thank you for giving some attention to it !

The question lacks focus.  There are advanced textbooks that cover the wide topic of which factors determine device speed.

CPUs and RAMs aren't made of logic gates.

@toolic it would be of great help if you could recommend some

'speed' of motherbaord, CPU or RAM is mainly market-speak. If you want to design with them, you need all sorts of much more detailed timing information. If you want to buy the right RAM for your mobo, then it's a number that has to match.

Are there any good resources that I can refer to, and what topic in particular should I study? Can you help me with it?

@SnappyRiffs If CPUs and RAMs are not made of logic gates, then please explain what they are made of.

@Neil_UK Incorrect advice. You can wery well use faster or slower RAM that the CPU or mobo is capable of supporting. The numbers don't have to match.

@Justme, Rams are made of transistors and capacitors (at least dram which is most common)

@Justme, maybe CPUs are made of logic gates

@SnappyRiffs I figured so. And what do these transistors do? Form logic gates. How does the data ends up in the capacitor? Through transistors of the logic gates.

@Justme Bidirectional multiplexors and tri-state drivers are not logic gates, but they are commonly employed.

@JohnDoty The DDR memory interface is a lot more than just bidir muxes and tri-state drivers. Also tri-state drivers must be CMOS logic gates made of transistors. Or is there another way of making them that does not require making the three-state logic and buffer stage?

@Justme Tri-state drivers are made of transistors, but they are not logic gates. Z is not a Boolean logic value. And they don't have to be CMOS, although they usually are these days.

@JohnDoty A buffer is two inverters. A three-state buffer internally needs AND plus OR functions to select between high, low, or hi-z output. Are you arguing that a buffer, especially three-state buffer is not a logic gate, but just made of transistors like all logic gates are? Is an inverter a logic gate? I think we may just have a disagreement that bunch of transistors working together is a logic gate to some people and not a logic gate to some other people. But the DDR interface must be complex enough to be classified as logic gate.

@vimalathithan17 You cannot express what a tri-state buffer does in terms of AND, OR, and NOT. None of these logical operators yields hi-Z as a result. You thus cannot build it from logic gates alone.

@Justme look at the transistor level for 74ls126 is it made of logic gates? NO

@JohnDoty But I can. The output is high if enabled and high, the output is low if enabled and low, the output is not driven if disabled. So is an open-drain logic gate is not a logic gate either? If NOT is a logic gate, is a buffer implemented with two NOTs a gate? Why is a three state buffer implemented with open-drain logic gates not a logic gate? It's just a bit more complex logic gate.

@SnappyRiffs look at transistor level implementation of 74HC125 or 74HC244 - is it a logic gate implementing a complex function with transistors - yes.

not only logic gates but uses external transistors

@SnappyRiffs It does not need external transistors. All transistors are on the die, inside the chip. The transistors are either on or off like with any other gate.

what i mean is that transistors and gates are used not only logic gates. also show me an image using pure logic gates

@Justme Try drawing it with nothing but logic gates. Logic gates either drive high or low, and cannot be disabled. You need another sort of element.

When acessing some data in a RAM chip, the process requires a few steps. First the microporcessor must set all the wires of the address bus to some voltage, representing the binary address. All the RAM chips in the system must look at this "address" and say "no, that's not me", or (one of them will say) "oh, that's me". Then that "selected" chip must "open a path" between its own internal array of stored voltages, and apply those voltages on the data bus.
This can't all happen instantly. First, it's impossible to instantaneously change voltage anywhere. Capacitance prevents that, and capacitance is everywhere, much to the chagrin of chip designers. Secondly, there are a lot of logic gates in a chain that must process these voltages in sequence, to be able to "open the channel" or "determine if an address is referring to me". Logic gates can't respond instantly, it takes time for them to produce a change of voltage at their outputs, in response to voltage changes at their inputs, and when you put a few of them in a sequence or chain, it takes a while for digital information to traverse that chain.
They can't respond instantly to some address appearing on the address bus. And once they know that they must respond, they can't instantly impose data onto the data bus. However, the designers of RAM chips can estimate the longest possible delay between an address appearing on the address bus, and the correct stored data being delivered to the data bus. This "maximum delay" will determine how many data transfer operations the RAM chip is guaranteed to be capable of performing, each second, and that's why RAM has a "speed" specification. That's the figure you see quoted, such as "266MHz", meaning that the RAM chips on this module can perform no more than 266 million data transfers per second.
The microprocessor has similar timing constraints. It also contains logic gates, which might each take one nanosecond to respond to input changes. Again, there are many gates at work, and many of them are in long sequences, introducing long delays for information to travel along the entire chain, totalling many nanoseconds of "delay". There are many modules inside a microprocessor, and they must all work together. For instance, the arithmetic section might take 20ns to add two numbers together. The two numbers must come from a subsection that might take 10ns to retrieve them from its registers. The result of the addition might take another 10ns to store somewhere.
All these operations must be coordinated. The microprocessor must wait for relevant sections to complete their individual tasks, before it can move on to the next task. For this, it employs a clock, each "tick" of which is a signal for the microprocessor to "do the next thing". Since each task takes time to complete, if the clock ticks too early, too frequently, the various subsystems will not have had sufficient time to complete their tasks, and errors occur, such as an incomplete addition result getting stored/used, or the RAM will not yet have presented valid data on the data bus.
Therefore, this clock signal has a maximum frequency, a number of "ticks per second" beyond which errors start occurring. That frequency is the figure quoted as "3GHz", meaning that the microprocessor will wait \$\frac{1}{3,000,000,000}s\$ after starting some task, before moving onto the next one.

There are other factors that limit the speed, the number of operations per second that RAM and microprocessors can achieve. Another constraint is the speed at which a voltage change can propagate down a length of conductor. These "potential waves" travel at a bit slower than light, but when you are talking about "billions of operations per second", that delay can be crippling. We often have to slow things down (fewer gigahertz) to allow time for digital signals to travel from place to place.
Another crippling constraint is that it takes energy to raise voltages, and energy to lower them again. Imagine trying to lift a weight from the floor to a table, and then having to lower it fast (I mean faster than gravity could do it alone). You would have to expend a lot of personal energy to do that, and digital circuits have the same problem. Every voltage change takes energy to produce, and that energy eventually becomes heat. You have to get that heat away from the system as fast as possible, to prevent the system melting itself.
If you haven't yet reached other speed limits, such as signal propagation delays, or speed of light constraints, you might be able to increase the system's clock frequency, called "over-clocking", but now you have a new enemy, heat.

This could be correct but very simplified and a bit outdated, not up to date with the context of the question about modern CPUs and their RAM. For example, memory controllers are integrated into CPU. They will tell a specific memory module to do something, the memory chips are basically not all on same bus listening if they should respond or not to a certain address. Also the speed is how many data transfers can be done per second on the interface, but there will be a delay between wanting to fetch or store data, and when it can be transferred, The daýs of chips capable of X MHz bus are gone.

@Justme I don't know of another way to explain these constraints, without writing a book.

@SimonFitch beautiful explanation sir! Thanks a lot for giving some of your precious time to write a long and elegant answer. Could you guide me with some resources like books,topics or blogs from which I can learn about this topic in deep. I don't know the name of specific topic under which this falls.Once again thanks a lot!

@Justme could you please elaborate or explain your thoughts and knowledge on this topic?

Logic gates take time to evaluate their inputs and produce outputs. If you're asking the circuit to produce output faster than the gates can do it, it won't work right.
How fast? It depends on the technology, the fabrication precision, the power supply voltage, the temperature, even the age of the part. When a part manufacturer states a speed, they are telling you that in specified test conditions, you may have confidence that the part will function at that speed.
A real part will generally operate at higher speed that the manufacturer's specification, but with reduced reliability. Above (and sometimes below) some speed, it will fail.

Thanks you for your answer,could you guide me with some resources so that I can dive a bit deep,I don't know what specific topic I should study

@vimalathithan17 I suggest Horowitz and Hill's "The Art of Electronics".

thanks a lot ! I'll look into it :)
